# Shorter way to instantiation PHP class

Tags: php, class

Say I have a class `Core()` where it will give me the instance of different classes depending on some initialization. Say that after initiating it, I get some class and then want to instantiate that. This is what I do:

```
$core = new Core();
// $core is further initiated
$api = $core->getClass(); // This returns, for instance class Library_MyClass
$class = new $api();
```

Is there a way to combine the last two steps into one? So for instance I say something like `$class = new $core->getClass()()`? Obviously what I wrote is wrong, but that is sort of what I want! Is that possible?

Comment: Normally you wouldn't have a class inside a class.  You should have them separated I would think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is some form of a factory you could do something like:

```
class Core
{
    public function getClass()
    {
        return new Library_MyClass();
    }
}

$core = new Core();
$class = $core->getClass();
```

However considering the name of the class `Core` I suspect you may be violating some [SOLID principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) here.

Comment: Yeah, it should be something like `getLibraryInstance()`.

Comment: The name `Core` was an example. I have a different name. The problem with your solution is that I would want to give the class some initialization, i.e. `new $class($param1, ...)` and since depending on what class I get, I may or may not pass parameter(s), I rather that my `Core` only returns the class name and I instantiate it myself later.

Comment: The SOLID principles sound like something out of a motivational poster that they would have in Microsoft HQ. Experimenting with what you can do is half the fun (actually, more) in programming. Open-source especially :) new tricks -> new features later. Besides, I think I have an idea of what the poster wants to do, possibly make a catch all for loading php class files.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to benefit from the use of [dependency injection](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html) (considering a slight update applied to PeeHaa example)

```
class Core
{
    public function getClass($api)
    {
        return new $api();
    }
}

$core = new Core();
$apiInstance = $core->getClass('Library_MyClass');
```

This way you won't have to update the `Core` class whenever you would like it to provide you with an instance of another library class.